# Resize Video Height and Width to that of A4. How to do?

Tags: video, graphics, adobe, converters, video-processing

Not typically a programming question but relates to graphics.
I need to resize a video such that when it is projected on a screen via a projector, it exactly takes space as much as an A4 sheet would do.
The Video is in High Definition - 1920x1080

As I understand, a video cannot be converted like we convert an image dimensions by specifying the height and width in Centimeters.

So, How should one go about it?
What would be the conversion to Centimeters?

[Here is the video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XDLmLYXuIDM)

Answer (score 0):

You **MUST** define your desired [DPI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dots_per_inch) on your output. You can fit a 1920x1080 in any size. The resolution of the video doesn't have anything to do with the size of the output. The only thing you need to know about the A4 is the proportion (A4 is 210mm x 297mm) so your video must have the same proportion. Use FFmpeg to resize your video. [Here](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/FilteringGuide) your can see a lot of examples on how to crop/resize your video with FFmpeg.

PS: Once your are using a projector instead of a monitor, it's even easier, with the video in the same proportion, just adjust your projector to fit the paper! It's equivalent.

Comment: Thank You! I've made a start